# Find partial text in cell

Tags: excel

I have large databases of people's titles.  I need to use a database I've created to assign that person a "focus" based on their title.  Essentially I need to do the following:

1) Paste titles in column B
2) Have column A output a "focus" (from column D) by recognizing a key word in column C that appears in the person's title

[image]

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What do you expect to show in the Focus cells? For row two, as an example, if `analysis` is in `D3`, do you want to show Analysis? It's unclear what you want to pull out, and how you're going to determine what cells to check through.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, there are no words from the person's title in B2 that appear anywhere in column D.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula to go into A2:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C:C,B2)),0))
```

Double click into A2, paste the formula then save it by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Replace the references to the entire columns C and D with fixed references to just your data ranges (preferably using table names) for better performance.